# Available options to build a custom search page with Tabs + Filters

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, search, spfx, pnp-search-webparts

I have a hub site which have 5 sites connected to it. now we are trying to build a custom search page as follow:-

[image]

with these main features

1. The search should only search the Hub site + the sites connected to the hub.
2. The search should have 4 tabs as follow:-

- All --> should show everything
- Sites --> should only show web pages
- People --> should only show people
- News --> should only show pages which are connected to specific content type

3. There should be filter panel using these fields:-

- Created
- Size of file
- Person
- File Type
- Author

So what are the available approaches to build something similar to the above?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your options are limited when it comes to modifying search experiences.

However, if you want to build enhance search experiences, [PnP modern search webparts](https://microsoft-search.github.io/pnp-modern-search/) is a good start, code base is maintained by community.

Comment: You can easily build tabs and filters with modern search webparts!

Comment: can you advice more which modern search web part you are talking about?